# MDS Worker Not Found

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, launchd, mds

I've removed MDS worker (to get rid of spotlight). In my console it looks like launchd is trying to find it. Anyone know how I could stop launchd for searching for spotlight? (ha)

```
10-12-10 9:39:27 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds[834]) Exited with exit code: 1
10-12-10 9:39:27 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
10-12-10 9:39:37 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds[838]) posix_spawn("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds", ...): No such file or directory
10-12-10 9:39:37 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds[838]) Exited with exit code: 1
10-12-10 9:39:37 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
10-12-10 9:39:47 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds[843]) posix_spawn("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds", ...): No such file or directory
10-12-10 9:39:47 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds[843]) Exited with exit code: 1
10-12-10 9:39:47 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
10-12-10 9:39:57 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds[844]) posix_spawn("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds", ...): No such file or directory
10-12-10 9:39:57 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds[844]) Exited with exit code: 1
10-12-10 9:39:57 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
10-12-10 9:40:07 AM com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds[845]) posix_spawn("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds", ...): No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to tell launchd to disable the mds daemon:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

(The `-w` makes the unload operation permanent -- without it, mds will be run again next time you reboot.)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist`.

Also, you could have just [disabled Spotlight](http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/20/disable-spotlight-in-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard/):

```
sudo mdutil -a -i off
```